# Complete generating sets for the following. Groebner basis

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, groebner-basis

Let $I $ denote the ideal in $Q [x,y,z]$ generated by $[x^2+y^2,xz−y,z^3−zy^3,xy+zy^2]$

Compute a generating set for $ I∩Q[y].$

Compute a generating set for $ I∩(y). $

Compute a generating set for $ (I:y) $

For $ I∩(y). $

I have set $(p1,p2,p3,p4)$ and the $ [x,0,z] $

Then I have obtained $ P1x^2 + P2xz + P3z^3 = 0 $

Is that the right step, and what do I do next?

I don't actually know where to start for the first generating set.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that it is an exam question, I propose the following solution:

Let's name the binomials:$$f_1=x^2+y^2 \\ f_2=xz-y \\ f_3=z^3-zy^3 \\ f_4=xy+zy^2 \\ I=\langle f_1, f_2, f_3, f_4\rangle$$

**I**. *A generating set for $I \cap \mathbb{Q}[y]$*

It means that we have to eliminate $x$ and $z$ from the equations $f_i=0, i=1,..,4$. This can be done by considering the $lex$ order $x>z>y$ and simply finding the Gröbner basis:
I used **Buchberger's algorithm** by finding the **S-polynomial** ($S(f_i,f_j)$) of each pair in $F=(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)$ and its remainder on division by F (denoted by $\overline{S(f_i,f_j)}^F, i\neq j$). If the remainder is not zero, it is added to $F$ until all $\overline{S(f_i,f_j)}^F=0$.

$$S(f_1,f_2) = xy+zy^2 =f_4 \in I \implies \overline{S(f_1,f_2)}^F=0 \\
  S(f_1,f_3) = x^2zy^3+z^3y^2 =zy^3f_1 +y^2f_3 \in I \implies \overline{S(f_1,f_3)}^F=0\\
S(f_1,f_4) = xzy^2-y^3 = y^2f_2 \in I \implies \overline{S(f_1,f_4)}^F=0\\
S(f_2,f_3) = xzy^3-z^2y = y^3f_2 + (y^4-z^2y) \notin I \implies \overline{S(f_2,f_3)}^F=-z^2y+y^4 \\
$$
Thus, we must add $f_5=-z^2y+y^4$ to our ideal $I$ and call it $I'$. Now, $F' = (f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4,f_5)$
$$S(f_1,f_5)=x^2y^4+y^3z^2y^4f_1-y^2f_5 \in I' \implies \overline{S(f_1,f_5)}^{F'}=0\\
S(f_2,f_4)=-z^2-y^2=yf_5+(-y^5-y^2) \notin I' \implies \overline{S(f_1,f_5)}^{F'}=-y^5-y^2
$$
Thus, we must add $f_6=-y^5-y^2$ to our ideal $I'$. Hence $F''=(f_1,...,f_6)$
It turns out that the remaining S-polynomials yield $\overline{S(f_1,f_6)}^{F''}=\overline{S(f_2,f_5)}^{F''}=\overline{S(f_2,f_6)}^{F''}=\overline{S(f_3,f_4)}^{F''}=\overline{S(f_3,f_5)}^{F''}=\overline{S(f_3,f_6)}^{F''}=\overline{S(f_4,f_5)}^{F''}=\overline{S(f_4,f_6)}^{F''}=\overline{S(f_5,f_6)}^{F''}=0$.

Therefore the Gröbner basis (It is easy to verify that it is also the reduced Gröbner basis by observing the leading terms) of I is $$G=\langle x^2+y^2, xz-y, z^3-zy^3, xy+z^2, z^2y-y^4, y^5+y^2\rangle$$
resulting in $I \cap \mathbb{Q}[y] =\langle y^5+y^2 \rangle$.

**II**. *A generating set for $I \cap \langle y \rangle$*

Like you started, we are looking for a polynomial $f \in I$ and $f \in \langle y \rangle$ at the same time. Let $$f=p_1f_1+p_2f_2+p_3f_3+p_4f_4 = q_1y \tag{1}$$ where $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ and $q_1$ are functions of $x,y$ and $z$. Our aim is to find $p_i,i=1,..,4$. $\{(y,0,0,0),(0,y,0,0),(0,0,y,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$ are trivial solutions. When $y=0$, equation $(1)$ becomes $$r_1x^2+r_2xz+r_3z^3=0 \tag{2}$$ where $r_i$ are functions of $x,z$. The generating set of all solutions of equation $(2)$ is $\{(z,-x,0),(0,z^2,-x),(z^3,0,-x^2)\}$.

Substituting these 7 solutions in equation $(1)$ gives us the following polynomials
$$g_1=x^2y+y^3\\
g_2=xyz-y^2\\
g_3=z^3y-zy^4\\
g_4=xy+zy^2\\
g_5=xy+zy^2=g_4\\
g_6=xzy^3-yz^2\\
g_7=x^2zy^3+z^3y^2=zy^2g_1+yg_3\\$$

Hence, the generating set for the given ideal is $\langle x^2y+y^3, xyz-y^2,z^3y-zy^4, xy+zy^2, xzy^3-yz^2 \rangle$. 
Note that this is not a Gröbner basis and finding it shouldn't be hard by following the same procedure for the first question. It turns out to be$$I \cap \langle y \rangle = \langle y^5+y^2, z^2y-y^4, xy+zy^2 \rangle$$

**III**. *A generating set for $I:y$*

There is a theorem that states if $\{h_1,...,h_p\}$ is a basis of the ideal $I \cap \langle g \rangle$, then $\{\dfrac{h_1}{g},...,\dfrac{h_p}{g}\}$ is a basis of $\langle I:g \rangle$. Therefore, $$I:y = \langle \frac{y^5+y^2}{y}, \frac{z^2y-y^4}{y}, \frac{xy+zy^2}{y} \rangle\\
= \langle y^4+y, z^2-y^3, x+zy \rangle$$

I have only briefly read the [Cox-Little-O'shea](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441922571) book and I have come up with this solution based on my understanding. Nonetheless, there might be a simpler solution or a way to shorten these computations (probably by using improvements of the Buchberger's algorithm). I will be happy to know if someone can suggest improvements or shortcuts to these approaches.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases i let the computer algebra system of my preference, today [sage](http://www.sagemath.org), to make the computations. Let us see the results:

```
sage: R.<x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(QQ)
sage: J = R.ideal( [ x^2+y^2, x*z-y, z^3-z*y^3, x*y+z*y^2] )
sage: J.elimination_ideal( [x,z] )
Ideal (y^5 + y^2) of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y, z over Rational Field
```

The message is as follows. First of all, the element $Y = y^2+y^5$ is in the posted ideal $J$:

```
sage: y^2+y^5 in J
True
```

The representation of this element w.r.t. the generators of $J$ is

```
sage: Y = y^2+y^5
sage: Y.lift(J)
[y^3, y*z^2 - y, -x*y, -x*y^2 + z]
```

Indeed, in
$$
y^3(x^2+y^2)+y(z^2-1)(xz-y)-xy\cdot z(z^2-y^3) + (z-xy^2)\cdot y(x+zy)
$$
there survive only the monomials in powers of $y$.

```
sage: y^3*(x^2+y^2)+y*(z^2-1)*(x*z-y)-x*y*z*(z^2-y^3) +(z-x*y^2)*y*(x+z*y)
y^5 + y^2
```

How to get this using Gröbner bases?
Unfortunately, the order of the letters `x,y,z` in the alphabet is not the order we need for our purposes, so let us consider the "same problem", but we eliminate $x,y$, and keep $z$. The corresponding code needs the `lex` order on the polynomial ring:

```
sage: R.<x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(QQ, order='lex')
sage: J = R.ideal( [ x^2+y^2, x*z-y, z^3-z*y^3, x*y+z*y^2] )
sage: J.elimination_ideal([x,y])
Ideal (z^5 + z^3) of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y, z over Rational Field
sage: J.groebner_basis()
[x^2 + y^2, x*y + y^2*z, x*z - y, y^3 + z^4, y^2*z^2 + y^2, y*z^4 + y*z^2, z^5 + z^3]

sage: (z^3+z^5).lift(J)
[0, -y^2*z, z^2 + 1, y*z^2]
```

Note that $z^3+z^5$ is the generator of the elimination ideal, after eliminating $x,y$, and the "last element" in the Gröbner basis.

The same with the elimination of $y,z$, we use the order `invlex`, the reverse lexicographic order:

```
sage: R.<x,y,z> = PolynomialRing(QQ, order='invlex')
sage: J = R.ideal( [ x^2+y^2, x*z-y, z^3-z*y^3, x*y+z*y^2] )
sage: J.elimination_ideal([y,z])
Ideal (x^8 + x^2) of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, y, z over Rational Field
sage: J.groebner_basis()
[z^3 - x^3, y*z^2 - x^4, x*z - y, y^2 + x^2, x*y + x^5, x^8 + x^2]

sage: (x^2+x^8).lift(J)
[-x^4*y^2 - x^2*y + x^6 + 1, -y*z^2 + x^3*y*z + y, x^3*y^2 + x*y, -x^3*z^2 - z + x^3*y^3 + x*y^2 + x^3]
```

Similarly, $x^2+x^8$ is the generator of the elimination ideal, after eliminating $y,z$, and the "last element" in the Gröbner basis.

Now i need some tiny contortion to set the order of the letters $x,y,z$ which places $y$ at the end, after $z$.

```
sage: R.<x,z,y> = PolynomialRing(QQ, order='lex')
sage: J = R.ideal( [ x^2+y^2, x*z-y, z^3-z*y^3, x*y+z*y^2] )
sage: J.elimination_ideal([x,z])
Ideal (y^5 + y^2) of Multivariate Polynomial Ring in x, z, y over Rational Field
sage: J.groebner_basis()
[x^2 + y^2, x*z - y, x*y + z*y^2, z^3 - z*y^3, z^2*y - y^4, y^5 + y^2]
```

This computes the ideal $J\cap \Bbb Q[y]$. (I was using $J$ instead of $I$, since $J$ is a free letter in `sage`.)

I do not know the notation $(I:y)$, but i think the above addresses by explicit computation the difficulties of the question, and a way to proceed.

Comment: This was an exam question, how would I compute this by hand, and do you agree with my answer for the second one?

Comment: This changes completely the answer to the question. Usually, computation have to be done as in the classes. In this case, it makes sense to search $p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4$ as main task, well, i posted a solution for $p_1\cdot (x^2+y^2)+\dots = 0$ only as a secondary product. But we search for it! So we set $y=0$ in this relation, getting $p_1(x,0,z)x^2+\dots =0$. Gröbner bases calculations in $\Bbb Q[x,z]$ should now exhibit $p_1(x,0,z),\dots$, so we know $p_1 = p_1(x,0,z)+y\cdot q_1(x,y,z)$. Same for $q_2,\dots$. Questions try now to get information on $q_1,q_2,\dots$. We need the course...